# Expectation of conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, expected-value

Let $G$ be a $\sigma$-field.

Is the statement:
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|G]] = \mathbb{E}[X]
$$
true even if X is **NOT** a G-random variable?

Comment: G-random variable? did you mean $\sigma(X) \subset G$

Comment: This is always true by the defintion of conditional expectation: when you integrate $E[X|G]$ over any set in $G$ you will get the same as when you integrate $X$ over the set, in psrticular it holds when the set is $\Omega$.

Comment: @JonathanHole Thanks! this helps a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what $G$-random variable means in this context. If you are saying that $X$ is independent of $G$, then
$$
\mathbb{E}[X|G] = \mathbb{E}[X],
$$
which implies
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|G]] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X]] = \mathbb{E}[X].
$$

Comment: I meant X is not necessarily G-measurable.